# Imprimir con Laravel VUE

Tags: vue.js, laravel-7

Estimados me estoy iniciado con Laravel y VUE, por favor si me ayudan.
Tengo un Formulario donde se ingresa un dato, mediante VUE se agrega dinámicamente con un botón o presionando INTRO, luego con otro Botón IMPRIMIR, la idea es enviar todos los registros al Controlador y obtener información desde el modelo o base de datos para luego utilizar esa información e imprimir con css especifico,
Por ejemplo: Ir agregando solo códigos de productos, para luego imprimir una hoja con otro css (diferente al del sitio) con informacion mas completa rescatada desde la base de datos (codigo producto, valor, ubicacion, etc, etc)

````
<div class="container mt-5">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-3">
        <input class="form-control"  v-model="nuevoCodigo" @keyup.enter="addCodigo">
    </div>

    <div class="col">
         <button @click="addCodigo" class="btn btn-success">CODIGO</button>
         <button class="btn btn-primary" @click="imprimir">Imprimir</button>
         {{result}}
    </div>

  </div>
    <p>
    <div v-for="(codigo, index) of codigos":key="index">
        <div class="alert alert-primary my-1" role="alert">
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                <div>
                    {{index + 1 }}.-&nbsp; {{codigo.idf}} <input v-model="codigo.idf">
                </div>
                <div>
                    <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" @click="delCodigo(index)">X</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


</template>
<script>
    export default
    {
        data(){
            return{
            codigos:[ ],
            nuevoCodigo:"",
            result: null
            }
        },
        methods:{
            addCodigo (){
                this.codigos.push({ idf:this.nuevoCodigo });
                this.nuevoCodigo="";
            },
             delCodigo (index){
               this.codigos.splice(index, 1);
            },
            imprimir() {
                        axios.post('rutaPrinted',{allcodigos: this.codigos}).then((response) => {
                        this.result = response.data;
                    });
                },
        },

    }
</script>```
````

Comment: No logro entender cuál sería el problema. ¿Hay algún error para solucionar?

Comment: Hola gracias por responder, la verdad he intentado con vue-html-to-paper, pero no encontré el resultado que espero, no sé como hacerlo, he buscado, pero me he quedado sin recursos para resoverlo